# Working with integer array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

The output of this array shows a compilation error,  if only the `a2.SumOfArray({12}, 12);` 
is commented, it compiles. How do I put it in an array form and get a working output?
Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Calculation
{

Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int total, I;

int SumOfArray(int data[], int size){

     System.out.print("Enter size of array: ");
     size = myScanner.nextInt();

         for(i=0; i<=size; i++){
             System.out.println("Enter number: ");
             data[i]=myScanner.nextInt();
             total=total+data[i];
         }

     System.out.println("Sum of Array: "+ total);
     return total;
 }


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Calculation a2 = new Calculation();
        **a2.SumOfArray({12}, 12);**

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `a2.SumOfArray({12}, 12);` is valid Java syntax?  Also, why pass a 1-element array and a size of 12?  Why pass the length at all, when you can get the length from the array.  Hint, it's `new int[] { ...}`

Comment: SumOfArray method is asking for int not array `SumOfArray(int data[], int size`...... do you meant to do `SumOfArray(int[] data, int size)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace :

```
a2.SumOfArray({12}, 12);
```

With

```
a2.SumOfArray(new int[]{12}, 12);
```

However, your code has compilation issue try to find those and fix that.

Answer (score 1):

With first glance at your code, there are couple mistakes: (they are not specific to Java8 btw)

1. your `SumOfArray` is taking two `int` for input not array. Change  `SumOfArray(int data[], int size)` to `SumOfArray(int[] data, int size)` to take a `int[]` array  for input. In java `int[]` means an int array.
2. then you need to pass in your array like this `a2.SumOfArray(new int[]{1,2,3}, 12);` you need the keyword `new` so the java compiler knows to reserve memory for this new array and you need the `int[]` to tell the compiler this is an int array.